# How do I change the color of the 'pages' text in the bibliography when using hyperref with pagebackref enabled?

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, color

I'm using `hyperref` to add pdf hyperlinks to all references in my document. 
I am using the `pagebackref` option, so in the bibliography I get a nice list of links to the pages the reference appeared. The page numbers are preceded by "-> pages" but this text is a light shade of grey.

I disabled colour boxes but I don't seem to be able to modify the colour of this text. Any ideas? It is too light right now. Here's the code I'm using:

```
\usepackage[bookmarks,bookmarksnumbered, colorlinks=true, allcolors=black,citecolor=black,
filecolor=black, linkcolor=black, pagecolor=black, urlcolor=black,
pagebackref,linktocpage
]{hyperref}
```

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

The question is, how do you configure hyperref to print the `"-> pages"` in the first place? By default it doesn't print it with the article class... So I suppose that you somehow modify the `\backref...` commands of hyperref and that the color is in there somewhere.

Here's an example how to change the text (and thus also the color) of the backlinks (found at http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3670&start=10 ):

```
\renewcommand*{\backreflastsep}{, }
\renewcommand*{\backreftwosep}{, }
\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{%
  \ifcase #1 %
    No citations.% use \relax if you do not want the "No citations" message
  \or
(page #4).%
  \else
(pages #4).%
  \fi%
}
```